# How to add Google Earth Engine data to Google Earth

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

I just found out about the [Google Earth Engine Catalogue](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog) and there are a few datasets that I want to take a look at. Is there an easy way to display some of these datasets in my desktop version of Google Earth? I would prefer not to download all of the datasets and then import them into Google Earth.

Comment: It's a little unfortunate that the names are so similar, but the products are unrelated.  You can't add Earth Engine data to Google Earth Pro without exporting to a local file (geotiff) that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to exporting a GeoTiff and loading that in Earth Pro (as mentioned in a comment), for larger datasets you can export a map tile set from EE, and load it into the Earth web client using the new Tile Layer functionality.

But generally, it's probably better to preview Earth Engine (EE) datasets in the EE Code Editor.  In fact, for most datasets in the EE Data Catalog, if you look at the bottom of the data page there is sample code that you can copy and paste into the code editor to preview the data, or just click the blue "Open in Code Editor" button.

Note that many of the datasets in EE are multispectral or other types of data, and are not natively RGB color images that can be directly viewed.  So for most of them you need to process and add visualization parameters before they can be visualized on a map... that's what the sample code is for.

Comment: Is there a better application than google earth (but which unlike EE code editor would live on my desktop) that can do things like view multispectral band imagery? But which would also just have google earth's satelite imagery build in?

Comment: There are several GIS packages like QGIS and ArcGIS which can view and manipulate multispectral imagery. They don't have Google Earth's imagery built in, but they do have some options for imagery basemaps through associated services or plugins.